# Snake Head Isn't Moving

Tags: python, pycharm, python-turtle

I was coding a basic snake game in the turtle module in Python and when I tested it, I saw that the snake head wasn't moving.

here is the code:

import modules:

```
import turtle
import random
import time
delay=0.1

# Background

win = turtle.Screen()
win.title("snake")
win.bgcolor("black")
win.setup(width=800, height=800)
win.tracer(0)
```

I tested it and it worked so I moved onto the snake head:

```
# snake head

head = turtle.Turtle()
head.speed(0)
head.shape("square")
head.color("white")
head.penup()
head.goto(0, 50)
head.direction = "stop"
```

moving the snake head:

```
# snake movement

def move():

    if head.direction == "up":
        y = head.ycor()
        head.sety(y + 20)

    if head.direction == "down":
        y = head.ycor()
        head.sety(y - 20)

    if head.direction == "right":
        x = head.xcor()
        head.setx(x + 20)

    if head.direction == "left":
        x = head.xcor()
        head.setx(x - 20)

# keyboard setting


def go_up():

    if head.direction != "down":
        head.direction = "up"


def go_down():

    if head.direction != "up":
        head.direction = "down"


def go_right():

    if head.direction != "left":
        head.direction = "right"


def go_left():
    if head.direction != "right":
        head.direction = "left"
```

Main game loop:

```
# main game loop
while True:
    win.update()
    move()
    time.sleep(delay)
```

And keyboard binding:

```
# keyboard binding

win.listen()
win.onkey(go_up, "w")
win.onkey(go_down, "s")
win.onkey(go_right, "d")
win.onkey(go_left, "a")
```

Also i have an error in the line `win.listen()` saying "This code is unreachable" if anybody knows what I did wrong please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it says the code is unreachable is because the key binding stuff, including `window.listen`, comes after the `while True:`  loop. Since you don’t have any way to exit the loop, the code after will never run. If there are not any key bindings, the snake will never change from the `"stop"` direction.

You should move the main game loop to the very end of your code, so everything else gets a chance to run.